# How to remove special characters from a string in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, regexp-replace

I am trying to remove using REGEXP_REPLACE the following special characters: `"[]{}`

from the following text field: `[{"x":"y","s":"G_1","cn":"C8"},{"cn":"M2","gn":"G_2","cn":"CA99"},{"c":"ME3","gn":"G_3","c":"CA00"}]`
and replace them with nothing, not even a space.

*Needless to say, this is just an example string, and I need to find a consistent solution for similar but different strings.

I was trying to run the following: `SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('[{"x":"y","s":"G_1","cn":"C8"},{"cn":"M2","gn":"G_2","cn":"CA99"},{"c":"ME3","gn":"G_3","c":"CA00"}] ','[{[}]":]','')`

But received pretty much the same string..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This looks like a JSON text. Why would you want to remove the structure from that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the special characters (`\`), and to specify that you want to repeat the operation for every characters (`'g'`) else it will stop at the 1st match

```sql
 SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
    '[{"x":"y","s":"G_1","cn":"C8"},{"cn":"M2","gn":"G_2","cn":"CA99"},{"c":"ME3","gn":"G_3","c":"CA00"}] ',
     '[{\[}\]":]',
     '',
     'g');
                  regexp_replace
--------------------------------------------------
 xy,sG_1,cnC8,cnM2,gnG_2,cnCA99,cME3,gnG_3,cCA00
(1 row)
```

Comment: ps: the question ask for removing `[]{}` and you example also removes `:"`, so I followed your example..

Comment: Hi JGH, thank you very much for your help, but as you mentioned in your comment, I need to keep on the `:` (which means that the example I gave is wrong), the required result should be as follows:
x:y,s:G_1,cn:C8,cn:M2,gn:G_2,cn:CA99,c:ME3,gn:G_3,c:CA00

Comment: @TalSibony so you can remove `:` from the regex_replace 2nd argument (`'[{\[}\]"]'`)

Comment: Owww no I see that it only requires removing the `:` from the second argument in your solution, thanks a lot!